# My code doesn't print ''No matches found'', why?

Tags: python

This is my code.
It doesn't print ''No matches found''
I think that it has to do with the section start program

```
scores_and_similarities = "somestring"  # value can be empty
similarities = scores_and_similarities.split(',')
if similarities == '':
    print('\tNo matches found')
for similarity in similarities:
    print('\t%s' % similarity)
```

Comment: `similarities = scores_and_similarities[1].split(',')` is a list, so it makes no sense comparing it to a string (`similarities == ''`).

Comment: I think you can reduce your question to a few lines, because the beginning of the code isn't relevant. I spent more time trying to find the offending part than to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`str.split` returns a `list` not a `string`. Test your value using truthiness instead:

```
similarities = scores_and_similarities.split(',')
if not similarities  # better than if similarities == []
    print('\tNo matches found')
```

note that `str.split` returns an empty list just when the input string is empty. So you could test

```
if not scores_and_similarities:
   print('\tNo matches found')
else:
   # split and process
```

although I suspect that you're expecting `str.split` to return empty list if string doesn't contain a comma but it's not:

```
>>> ''.split(",")
>>> []
>>> 'iii'.split(",")
['iii']
```

so maybe you want to test if `,` is in the string (note: testing if splitted string has 1-length does the same:

```
if ',' not in scores_and_similarities:
   print('\tNo matches found')
```

Comment: It does not work after trying the above. I'm not sure why.

Comment: If I try solution 1, it repeats no matches... for every line and if I do the second solution it doesn't appear.

Comment: check your input string. Empty: should work, no comma: sure it doesn't check my edit why. Print the string you want to split just to check.

Answer (score 0):

This is because after the split it returns empty list `[]` not an empty string `''`.

```
scores_and_similarities = "somestring"  # value can be empty
similarities = scores_and_similarities.split(',') # empty list is returned
if similarities == '': # [] is not equal to ''
    print('\tNo matches found')
for similarity in similarities:
    print('\t%s' % similarity) # so answer is this
```